# SAPUI5 Firefox SecurityError: The operation is insecure. sap-ui-core.js 144:0

Tags: javascript, firefox, sapui5

I have a problem running a SAPUI5 application locally with Firefox (and only Firefox).

If I deploy the application to an SAP system it seems also working with Firefox.

I run the application locally out of Eclipse with SAP development tools. I also setup a proxy (Web.xml) so that I should not have any same origin policy problems.

With all browsers it works fine, but not with Firefox.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to debug this problem.
Only information from Firefox Javascript Console:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure. sap-ui-core.js:144:0
```

It seems also not possible to switch to the debug mode of SAPUI5 by using `Strg+Alt+Shift+P` because the problem occurs during start-up.

I am trying to use the lib from the internet (to test the latest version before deploying anything to a real SAP system).

```
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js
```

Anyone an idea what the problem could be or how I could get more log informations out of Firefox?

The obvious solution using -dbg instead, sorry my fault..

Now I got following message:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure. sap-ui-core-dbg.js:36186:0
```

And this points to the function:

```
    getStatistics : function() {
        return this.statistics || window.localStorage.getItem("sap-ui-statistics") == "X";
    },
```

Something in the return statement seems to be insecure?

Comment: Try loading `sap-ui-core-dbg.js`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a Firefox and/or Plug-In problem. I reseted all Firefox settings and reinstalled my Plug-Ins and now it works. Maybe it helps others with the same issue. Anyhow I had that problem only with "some" SAPUI5 pages.
See also: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/560

Answer (score 0):

Gecko throws the error message when cookies are disabled.

Change:

```
if (window.localStorage)
```

To:

```
if (document.cookie && window.localStorage)
```